# Backbone.js TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying out Backbone.js and pretty new to it but cannot pin down on binding this.listenTo properly in the View initialize function in the following code.

This backbone code is a separate js file.

```
    'use strict';

let Preloadcart = function ( $, Backbone, _ ) {
  // console.log(Backbone);
  console.log(this);
  let
    // fnSelf = this,
    // Model-each unit comprises of this
    Service = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults:{
        title:'',
        price: 0,
        checked: false
      },

      type: 'Service',

      toggleCheck: () => {
        this.set('checked', !this.get('checked'));
      }
    }),

    // Collection- of such Service instances
    ServiceList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

      // collection based on this model
      model: Service,

      type: 'ServiceList',

      // get model instances with attribute checked=true
      getChecked: () => {
        console.log(`checking ${this.type}`);
        return this.where({checked:true});
      },
    }),

    services = new ServiceList([
            new Service({ title: 'web development', price: 200}),
            new Service({ title: 'web design', price: 250}),
            new Service({ title: 'photography', price: 100}),
            new Service({ title: 'coffee drinking', price: 10})
            // Add more here
        ]),

    // View of each Service model unit
    ServiceView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'li',

      type: 'ServiceView',

      events: {
        'click': 'toggleService'
      },

      initialize: () => {
        console.log(`initializing ${this.type}`);
        _.bindAll(this, 'toggleService', 'render');

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
      },

      toggleService: () => {
        this.model.toggle();
      },

      render: () => {
        let
          $frag = $(document.createDocumentFragment()),
          $htmlCheckbox = $('<input>', {
            type:'checkbox',
            value: 1,
            name: this.model.get('title'),
          }),
          $htmlSpan = $('<span>', {
            value: `\$${this.model.get('price')}`,
          });

        $htmlCheckbox.append(this.model.get('title'));
        $htmlCheckbox.append($htmlSpan);
        this.$htmlCheckbox.prop('checked', this.model.get('checked'));

        $frag.append($htmlCheckbox);
        this.$el.append($frag);

        return this;
      }
    }),

    App = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: $('#main'),

      type: 'App',

      initialize: function () {
        // listen on the collection instance of ServiceList, services
        console.log(`initializing App ${this.type}`);
        let
          view, that= this;
        this.total = 0,
        this.collection = services;

        _.bindAll(this, 'render');

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);

        _(this.collection.models).each( (model) => {
          view = new ServiceView();
          view.set({model: model});
          that.$('#services').append(view.render().el);
        }, this);
      },

      render: () => {

        _.each(this.collection.getChecked(), (each) => {
          this.total += each.get('price');
        });

        this.$('#total-value').text(`\$${this.total}`);
      }
    }),

    AppView = new App();

  // new App();
  // return App;

};


export default Preloadcart;
```

This is called in the main js file something like this:

```
$(() => {
          Preloadcart($, Backbone, _, that);
        });
```

but throws the error:

```
preloadCart.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

The problem as I trace in the error log seems here:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'toggleService', 'render');
```

and

```
console.log(`initializing ${this.type}`);
```

under ServiceView `intialize` function;

`this` is undefined when I output. what am i missing?

Let me know if there's any confusion about the code, I will try to make this simpler.

Comment: `$el: $('#main')` is bizarre, why are you doing that? Your `Function.prototype.bind` call on the `initialize` value is also bizarre, what do you expect `this` to be in that context and why are you trying to `bind` there?

Comment: @muistooshort `$el` - so that whenever that element is selected that's the value im selecting.

bind - That means I must have tried everything and as a last resort tried to bind to the `this` which is `App`

Comment: @muistooshort most examples I see are like this http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html the function inside a jQuery.
but what if I m running a backbone js file imported into, say a main file. how would you suggested that should be run?

Comment: Where in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org) does it say to supply `$el` like that? Why are trying to bind `initialize` at all? Why would you expect `this.listenTo` to work when you've bound `initialize` to the wrong `this`? I'd recommend going back to the tutorials and trying to build this piece by piece.

Comment: Lets forget $el for a while @muistooshort.  Ive tried without without any bindings. as well. if tis script is say file.js and then i import and run it as ive outlined above in the question, it still gives the same error. this particular error btw, shouldn't have anything to do with $el

Comment: @muistooshort I can name $<somethingKey>:<someValu> correct?

Comment: and in this.listenTo, `this` refers to App view ?

Comment: @user2290820 Please remove all the weird code + code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem and post a [mcve]. then someone will be interested to actually read your question and answer it...

Comment: @user2290820 stuff like `$list: $('#services'),` is not good practice. View should not be aware of things outside it.

Comment: @TJ I am not in a position to know what is a good practice and not in backbone. where should the $list be?

Comment: @TJ give me sometime to comeup with a jsfiddle

Comment: @user2290820 if it's outside the view, it's should not exist in this context. If it's inside the view, it should be `this.$('#services')` than `$('#services')`

Comment: @TJ So views are independent. only models can parse DOM?

Comment: @user2290820 views should be independent. They can share data by sharing models, communicate via triggering events etc. But one view shouldn't accessing some element outside of it's element and manipulating it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113071/discussion-between-user2290820-and-t-j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initialize: () => {
        console.log(`initializing ${this.type}`);
        _.bindAll(this, 'toggleService', 'render');

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
      },
```

The Arrow Operator is called when the initialize function is defined.
just when the Preloadcart is called. So in function initialize,'this' is not the viewobject,but the 'this' when Preloadcart is called. use normal function.

```
initialize: function() {
            console.log(`initializing ${this.type}`);
            _.bindAll(this, 'toggleService', 'render');

            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
          },
```

Comment: ah you are so right. this anonymous operator has been easy to write but a  big pain-in-you know where. let me see if that works.

Comment: Arrow operator should be used in function,not the time when define a Prototype.

Comment: you know your javascript

Comment: beauty always lead to pain